# Calculating an expression using recursive formulas

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I calculate this:
($\dots$(((2 * 3) * 4) * 5) * $\dots$) * 2017 ;
if x * y = $\frac{x + y}{1 + xy}$, (notice x*y is not multiplication). This should be calculated using recursive formulas only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $ \star $ is associative
\begin{eqnarray*}
x \star y \star z = \frac{x+y+z+xyz}{1+xy+yz+zx}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now if 
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(X)=(X-x)(X-y) (X-z) =X^3+X(xy+yz+zx)-(X^2(x+y+z)+xyz)
\end{eqnarray*}
then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(1) =1+(xy+yz+zx)-((x+y+z)+xyz) \\
g(-1)=1+(xy+yz+zx)+((x+y+z)+xyz) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
x \star y \star z = \frac{x+y+z+xyz}{1+xy+yz+zx} =\frac{g(-1)-g(1)}{g(-1)+g(1)}
\end{eqnarray*}
And a similar arguement will work for more iterands.

Now define 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(X)=(X-2)(X-3) \cdots (X-2017)
\end{eqnarray*}
then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \star 3 \cdots 2016 \star 2017 = \frac{f(-1) -f(1)}{f(-1)+f(1)} =\frac{2018! -2 \times 2016!}{2018! + 2 \times 2016!}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Could you please give a more detailed explanation on your solution. What does X equal to and why are -1 and 1 the arguments to the function.

Comment: [+1] Besides, it can be connected to $\tan$ and $\arctan$ functions. See for example (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1876639).

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$x*y*z=x*z*y$$
$$2*4=\frac23; 2*4*6*8=\frac45; \cdots 2*4*\cdots *2014*2016=\frac{1008}{1009}.$$
$$3*5=\frac12; 3*5*7*9=\frac23; \cdots 3*5*\cdots *2015*2017=\frac{504}{505}
$$
$$\frac{1008}{1009}*\frac{504}{505}=...$$